# Error installing Gulp and Bower

Tags: node.js, wordpress, npm, bower

I am pretty new to using terminal and installing gulp, but I am running through a few errors. Errors keep popping up and I am not sure why. My goal for right now is to `npm install -g gulp` and after that  `npm install -g bower` so I get start using Sega Wordpress Started Theme, but not sure if any old files are interfering. Maybe a clean out and reinstall would work? Error is below. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`npm install -g <package>` installs globally, so you need to run with `sudo` in order to be able to write to the correct destination folders.

Comment: Hello I have done the first sudo and after done that what next. https://gyazo.com/95782d17bd1d79006155447b97e41ec3 @slugonamission

Comment: It's installed, there's nothing else to do.